# FetchError: invalid json response body at http://localhost:3000/api/products/6092ca3460fc67315178f2fa reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: mongodb, next.js

I am trying to fetch data from MongoDB, but apparently, it gives an error
FetchError: invalid json response body at
http://localhost:3000/api/products/6092ca3460fc67315178f2fa reason: Unexpected token < in JSON     at position 0

```
const defaultEndpoint = 'http://localhost:3000/api/products/';

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(defaultEndpoint);
    const data = await res.json();

    const paths = data.map (product => {
        return {
             params: { id: product._id.toString() }
        }
    })

    return {
        paths,
        fallback: false
    }

}

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
    const id = context.params.id;
    const res = await fetch ('http://localhost:3000/api/products/' + id);
    const data = await res.json ();

    return {
        props: {product: data}
    }
}

const Details = ({product}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{product.title}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Details


API Endpoint which is perfectly working on http://localhost:3000/api/products

import { connectToDatabase } from "../../util/mongodb";

export default async (req, res) => {
  const { db } = await connectToDatabase();

  const products = await db.collection("products").find({}).toArray();

  res.json(products);
};
```

Comment: Is that a valid ID in the request? That endpoint doesn't seem to be returning the expected response. Can you show the code for that endpoint?

Comment: can u debug whether your mongoDB is giving u the desire results by console.log(products) ? And what's the code for handling `:id`?

Comment: https://youtu.be/isPLzRplqQE
I am struggling to find the error for 2 weeks now. I am a new starter and I am getting exhausted. Could someone advise me and confirm where is my error? I am fetching data from MongoDB Atlas to the Next JS app. I have got the whole array mapped on the index page, but I cannot get the dynamic route to the particular user. Shall I change the DB or what are the solutions? I also recorded a video. Any help will be much appreciated. Many thanks